# Como selecionar contatos duplos de uma tabela

Tags: sql, postgresql

Eu possuo 2 tabelas :

- Usuarios [id, nome, etc ...]
- Amigos [id, idUsuario, idAmigoI]

Na tabela Amigos, idUsuario corresponde ao id do usuario que possui o contato e idAmigo o id do usuario que é de fato o contato.

Eu queria fazer duas funções (ou apenas um select bem grande) no postgresql , uma que fizesse um select com todas as amizades que ambos tivessem (A amigo de B e B amigo de A), e outra que fizesse o select de todas que  apenas um tivesse (A amigo de B e B não amigo de A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ficar mais fácil de entender, criei as duas tabelas com as colunas informadas:

```
CREATE TABLE Usuarios (
  id integer,
  nome varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Amigos (
  id integer,
  idUsuario integer,
  idAmigo integer
);
```

Como não foi informado, considerei que na tabela `Amigos` sempre será preenchido o `idUsuario` e o `idAmigo`. Após criar as tabelas, inseri alguns dados:

```
  INSERT INTO Usuarios
    VALUES (1, 'A');
  INSERT INTO Usuarios
    VALUES (2, 'B');
  INSERT INTO Usuarios
    VALUES (3, 'C');
  INSERT INTO Usuarios
    VALUES (4, 'D');
  INSERT INTO Usuarios
    VALUES (5, 'E');

  INSERT INTO Amigos
    VALUES (1, 1, 2);
  INSERT INTO Amigos
    VALUES (2, 1, 3);
  INSERT INTO Amigos
    VALUES (3, 2, 1);
  INSERT INTO Amigos
    VALUES (4, 2, 3);
  INSERT INTO Amigos
    VALUES (5, 3, 1);
  INSERT INTO Amigos
    VALUES (6, 3, 2);
  INSERT INTO Amigos
    VALUES (7, 4, 1);
  INSERT INTO Amigos
    VALUES (8, 4, 3);
  INSERT INTO Amigos
    VALUES (9, 4, 5);
  INSERT INTO Amigos
    VALUES (10, 5, 4);
```

Para retornar os usuários e seus amigos, é só fazer alguns `inner joins`:

```
SELECT
  u1.nome || ' é amigo de ' || u2.nome amizade
FROM Amigos a
INNER JOIN Usuarios u1
  ON (u1.id = a.idUsuario)
INNER JOIN Usuarios u2
  ON (u2.id = a.idAmigo);
```

O resultado do `select` é:

```
A é amigo de B
A é amigo de C
B é amigo de A
B é amigo de C
C é amigo de A
C é amigo de B
D é amigo de A
D é amigo de C
D é amigo de E
E é amigo de D
```

Para retornar aqueles usuários que possuem amigos, porém seus amigos não tem eles como amigos, você pode fazer:

```
SELECT
  u1.nome || ' é amigo de ' || u2.nome || ', porém ' || u2.nome || ' não é amigo de ' || u1.nome amizade
FROM Amigos a
INNER JOIN Usuarios u1
  ON (u1.id = a.idUsuario)
INNER JOIN Usuarios u2
  ON (u2.id = a.idAmigo)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Amigos ai WHERE ai.idUsuario = a.idAmigo AND ai.idAmigo = a.idUsuario);
```

O resultado do `select`é:

```
D é amigo de A, porém A não é amigo de D
D é amigo de C, porém C não é amigo de D
```

Infelizmente não tenho o Postgre instalado para verificar, porém fiz um teste no sqlite e funcionou perfeitamente.

Espero que tenha ajudado!